# Can i have PHP folder only from XAMPP 1.7.4?

Tags: php, version, xampp, upgrade, directory

I am currently using:
- Windows XP
- XAMPP 1.6.8 with (PHP 5.2.6)

I just want to upgrade PHP from XAMPP.
So i just want to **download "php" folder only** and i don't want the whole bundle.
It is huge to download (My connection speed is so slow).
Where can i get like that?
(or) Can anyone please upload the zipped?

Note: I've tested with the native PHP (extracted from php-5.3.5-Win32-VC6-x86.zip) from http://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/archives
But didn't work out!
That's why i wanna test with the PHP inside XAMPP.

Comment: download "php" folder only? http://php.net/downloads.php ? you could just get that and backup your xampp php, then plug those in and adjust to your needs? Not sure what you mean actually ;)

Comment: ) no one upload the zipped for u hmmmm

Comment: @robx: I've tested with the native PHP (extracted from php-5.3.5-Win32-VC6-x86.zip) from http://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/archives
But didn't work out!
That's why i wanna test with the PHP inside XAMPP.

Answer (score 0):

I have WAMP on XP, when i tried to install the new PHP only it installed perfectly but the WAMP did not started :(
So i'll advice you to go for the full bundle !

Comment: Yeh ;( Full Bundle's better. But it is too big for me to DL.

Answer (score 0):

You can take the whole bundle through your Friend also, if ur net sped is slow hmmmmm